# Adding a function from c# to c++

Tags: c#, c++

I am trying to fix and compile a c++ project but while I understand the error, I am not sure how to fix it as it involves a crossover between c# and C++.

The two functions below that are causing the errors are due to the cryptor variable not being defined:

```
  C++ Function:

  #Include RawData.h
  void decryptAllBytes(char* buffer)
{
std::list<char> returnBytes;
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof rawData; i++)
{
    if (j == (sizeof cryptor - 1))
    {
        j = 0;
    }
    returnBytes.push_back(rawData[i] ^ cryptor[j]);
    j++;
}
j = 0;
for (std::list<char>::iterator it = returnBytes.begin(); it != returnBytes.end(); ++it) {
    buffer[j] = *it;
    printf("writing: %d\n", *it);
    j++;
  }
}

     void getDecryptedBytes(int index, int size, char* buffer)
{
std::list<char> returnBytes;
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof rawData; i++)
{
    if (j == (sizeof cryptor - 1))
    {
        j = 0;
    }
    if (i >= index && i < (index + size))
    {
        returnBytes.push_back(rawData[i] ^ cryptor[j]);
    }
    else if (i >= (index + size))
    {
        break;
    }
    j++;
}
j = 0;
for (std::list<char>::iterator it = returnBytes.begin(); it != returnBytes.end(); ++it) {
    buffer[j] = *it;
    //printf("writing: %d\n", *it);
    j++;
  }
}
```

RawData.h looks like this (shortened for brevity)

```
     #ifndef RAWDATA_H_
     #define RAWDATA_H_

 /* 
 StartOffset(h): 00000000, EndOffset(h): 0000F96F, Length(h): 0000F970 */

 unsigned char rawData[63] = {
0xBB, 0xE5, 0x3A, 0x72, 0x65, 0xF4, 0x12, 0x65, 0x79, 0xB9, 0x73, 0x26,
0x3A, 0xFE, 0x33, 0x38, 0x6A, 0x4B, 0x57, 0x3D, 0x36, 0x64, 0x01, 0x44,
0xDA, 0x5B, 0xC0, 0xF4, 0x07, 0x47, 0x98, 0x40, 0x2A, 0x30, 0x3E, 0x04,
0x38, 0xDB, 0x9C, 0x20, 0x09, 0x74, 0x4B, 0x65, 0x79, 0x67, 0x39, 0x27,
0x55, 0x5B, 0x52, 0x30, 0x75, 0xD5, 0xA7, 0x0F, 0x09, 0x52, 0xAA, 0x93,
0x21, 0x5B, 0x24, 0x9C, 0xA3, 0xF0, 0x2B, 0x01, 0xF6, 0x67, 0xEE, 0x77,
0x58, 0x58, 0x6D, 0x73, 0xEF, 0x6B, 0x88, 0x94, 0x43, 0xCA, 0xFD, 0xCF,
0x1E, 0x84, 0x1A, 0x39, 0x25, 0x69, 0x40, 0xE5, 0xFF, 0x4C, 0x37, 0xF1,

 };


     #endif
```

The original cryptor function is written in c# in a different project, the code is as follows:

```
   C# Function:     
   char[] cryptor = new char[] { 'S', 'e', 'c', 'r', 'e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y', '\0' };

    namespace Cryptor
 {
    class Program
  {
    static byte[] XorByteArray(byte[] origBytes, char[] cryptor)
    {
        byte[] result = new byte[origBytes.Length];
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < origBytes.Length; i++)
        {
            if (j == cryptor.Length - 1)
            {
                j = 0;
            }
            byte res = (byte)(origBytes[i] ^ Convert.ToByte(cryptor[j]));
            result[i] = res;
            j += 1;
        }
        return result;
     }
```

I am guessing I need to add:

```
    char[] cryptor = new char[] { 'S', 'e', 'c', 'r', 'e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y', '\0' };
```

but doing so does not reliquinsh the visual studio errors (probably due to it not being c++ but c#). Can anybody point me in the right direction please?

Comment: I cannot see any relationship between c# and C++ code

Comment: The first function is in a c++ project but the second is part of a c# project. I have to admit, they look identical. I am not comfortable enough with c++ to know if they overlap

Comment: Can you tell, what exactly you are trying to do

Comment: Add in the cryptor variable to the top function so that it works. As it is not defined at the moment, I thought I would have to add in the variable but all attempts have so far failed

Comment: Are you remaking the C# function on C++?

Comment: no just trying to get the c++ function to work. The c# function was to xor the data and the c++ function is to decrypt it

Comment: please add the error that you are getting

Comment: The visual studio error is:The variable cryptor has not been defined

Comment: I need to define it above the function to get rid of the error, I am just not sure how to define it correctly

Comment: but adding char[] cryptor = new char[] { 'S', 'e', 'c', 'r', 'e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y', '\0' }; does not seem to work which would be the obvious answer

Comment: what is rawData var?

Comment: @yaodav a C byte array

Comment: where is he defined?

Answer (score 0):

going by your requirement this will compile/run, but there is not really enough information to know what it is meant to do...

```
void decryptAllBytes(char* buffer)
{
    const int raw_size = 20; // How big is rawData?? -here is some arbitrary value
    char * rawData = new char[raw_size];
    char * cryptor = new char[10];
    strcpy(cryptor, "secretkey");
    const int crypt_size = strlen(cryptor);  // get cypt size by strlen since its null terminated

    printf("rs: %d\n", raw_size);
    printf("cs: %d\n", crypt_size);

    std::list<char> returnBytes;
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < raw_size; i++)
    {
        if (j == crypt_size)
        {
            j = 0;
        }
        returnBytes.push_back(rawData[i] ^ cryptor[j]);
        j++;
    }
    j = 0;
    for (std::list<char>::iterator it = returnBytes.begin(); it != returnBytes.end(); ++it) {
        buffer[j] = *it;
        printf("writing: %d\n", *it);
        j++;
    }
}
```

Note: using sizeof on a pointer will always yield 8 since that is the byte-size of a pointer and has nothing to do with the length of your arrays (or whatever size a pointer is on your system). So I have changed those to use strlen or a constant.

But I have no idea what it will do. I don't know what rawData is supposed to contain or how it is setup?

I have populated cryptor with "secretkey" - here it is running - but as I say, I have no idea what its really meant to do: https://godbolt.org/z/C4edmi

What you probably need to do is re-write this. Its a bit of a mess - it uses some STL (standard template lib) and some raw pointers...

Comment: thanks. The function is supposed to take the byte array and decrypt it using the secret key and return the original. I will try this now to see if it works and then once it works, try and rewrite it using it as a base! Appreciate the help!!

Comment: I have added the second function so hopefully it gives some more clarity. My first question I have asked on here so not sure how much code is too much and takes away from the question as t ohow much I need to show for the whole picture!

Comment: These are the errors that visual studios 2019 give me:  'cryptor': undeclared identifier,   identifier "cryptor" is undefined,  'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. I have tried to update the question with more information to help show what I am trying to do. Thanks everyone

Comment: Well, as I say, there are a lot of issues with this code - using char arrays is ok, but it might be better to start to use std::vectors or std::arrays or other containers - even std::string, rather then raw char arrays, then you don't need to use strlen or strlen_s etc...

Comment: thanks for your help @code_fodder, I will probably try and rewrite some of it as a learning mechanism once it works. I am still not too familiar with c++!

Answer (score 0):

Lets start by simplifying the c# code a bit. Notably, the result array is passed as an parameter, and the indexing to the cryptor array is done by the modulus operator:

```
static void XorByteArray(byte[] origBytes, byte[] cryptor, byte[] result)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < origBytes.Length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = (byte)(origBytes[i] ^ cryptor[i % cryptor.Length]);
    }
}
```

When converting this to c++ we need to use char instead of bytes. In addition, C  arrays do not know their length, so we need to pass in this as a separate parameter. Otherwise the methods look mostly the same.

```
void XorByteArray(char* origBytes, int origLength, char* cryptor, int cryptorLength, char* result)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < origLength; i++)
    {
        result[i] = (origBytes[i] ^ cryptor[i % cryptorLength]);
    }
}
```

To call this we need to create the data, the key, and result arrays. Keep in mind that C "strings" are null terminated and uninitialized. In this example the arrays are zero initialized, and we skip 'encrypting' the null terminator to be able to print the strings:

```
int main()
{
    char bytes[10] = "test abcd";
    char key[2] = { 'a', 'b' };
    char encrypted[10] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 };
    char decrypted[10] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 };;
    XorByteArray(bytes, 9, key, 2, encrypted);
    XorByteArray(encrypted, 9, key, 2, decrypted);

    std::cout << encrypted << "\r\n";
    std::cout << decrypted;
}
```

Comment: I think I see what you are trying to explain. If I added cryptor = char bytes[9] { 'S', 'e', 'c', 'r', 'e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y',}; would that work with the current c++ code functions? I am afraid that if I start rewriting functions before I get it working, I might go too far down the rabbit hole to get it working at all

Comment: No, That would not be sufficient since you do not have the length of the array. You cannot use sizeof as you do in your code. There are also other issues, like not knowing the length of the input array. using list instead of vector etc. A good place to start would be deciding if you want to use C-data types like arrays, or c++ types, like std::string and std::vector.

Comment: I think what I will probably do is take out the encrypted function for now while I play around with it and try and move it back in later.  If I remove void DecryptAllBytes and use this function instead to just return the RawData as is, unless there is a problem with that which will break the code?

Comment: void getDecryptedBytes(int index, int size, char* buffer)
{
std::list<char> returnBytes;
int j = 0;
(int i = 0; i < sizeof rawData; i++)
j = 0;
for (std::list<char>::iterator it = returnBytes.begin(); it != returnBytes.end(); ++it) {
    buffer[j] = *it;
    //printf("writing: %d\n", *it);
    j++;
  }
}

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. There should not be any issue having both functions in the code and test to see what works. It might help to know what you are actually trying to do, is it just for learning? assignment? Obsfucation? You would rarely use code like this for actual security related stuff.